# ASP.NET on Publishing Web Page adds the code behind

Tags: asp.net, webforms

[image: For some reason I have code behind when publishing site]

I know how to do it in project ,but It is NOT a project rather a web page.

I don't want the code behind to be published.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Are you asking why your vb files are being published to your website as well as your aspx pages?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asking.

Comment: Have you looked at precompiled Web Site Projects(WSP)? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-vb

Comment: Is this a web application project (File->New Project), or a web site "project" (File->New Web Site)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it is a website.

Comment: Then you may not realize that it's normal for web sites to include the source. The source gets compiled on the fly. Some people think that's a good thing. It's one reason I never use web site "projects". They are very strange.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I noticed that and I took KHeaney's link. If I wanted to exclude the code behind, I had to modify to add assemblies of the pages instead of the adding code behind.

Comment: The alternative is to avoid web site "projects". They are unlike any other project type in Visual Studio, and not in a good way.